# JMF CannotRealizeException when reading mov files

Tags: java, jmf, .mov

The below code is a simple wrapper for the JMF player. After trawling through countless fruitless google searches, I come here to ask why this code results in the error down below.

##### Goal: Be able to embed and play a .mov file into a JFrame

###### Purpose: Play a cutscene in a game with minimal external libaries

```
    public class Video {
        Player player;
    
        public Video(String filepath, JFrame f) {
            MediaLocator mediapath = new MediaLocator("file:///" + "./src/main/resources/" + "video.mov");
            try {
                this.player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediapath);
                f.add(this.player.getVisualComponent()); // pull out the video component, add it to the jframe
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    
        public void play() {
            this.player.start();
        }
    }
```

```
 Unable to handle format: mp4a, 1000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, BigEndian, Signed, FrameSize=32 bits
 Unable to handle format: AVC1, 640x640, FrameRate=30.0, Length=59353
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@15d9bc04
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@15d9bc04
javax.media.CannotRealizeException
    at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005)
    at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:554)
    at <package>.Video.<init>(Video.java:19)
```

Comment: It might be that (the very old) JMF does not support the MP4 encoding.

Comment: i mentioned that i was looking for the capability to play .mov files, however any video format is acceptable

Comment: There are MOV format files that JMF *will* play. The problem is most, if not all, video formats are 'container formats' and the encodings (e.g. MP4) within that container will not necessarily be recognised. What is this media player for? Can you encode all the possible videos in an old (often quite inefficient) encoding?

Comment: I edited the question to include a purpose, but I'm not sure how to change the encoding

Comment: ***"Purpose: Play a cutscene in a game with minimal external libaries"*** Uh-huh, so you control all the media needing to be played. It is not for the users to trawl round their local file-system to play any vid they have. *"I'm not sure how to change the encoding"* Video editing tools usually offer the user a choice of encoding when saving out vids. It might also be a problem with the video resolution, though I vaguely recall playing some huge MOVs (made from high-res photos using `JPEGImagesToMovie`).

Comment: Do you have an example of an mov file you could play?

Comment: Nope. I might have had one or two on my 'data' drive, but it is kaput at the moment.

Comment: Any advice on how to reformat something into smth jmf can play?